# Windows10から リモートデスクトップ接続でAlmalinux9.2 にXvnc でログインすると直ぐに切れてしまう

Tags: linux

journalctl のエラーを追加しました。　2023/10/05

Oct 05 14:33:28 xxx_xxx xrdp[7253]: [INFO ] starting xrdp with pid 7253
Oct 05 14:33:28 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7252]: [INFO ] starting xrdp-sesman with pid 7252
Oct 05 14:33:28 xxx_xxx xrdp[7253]: [INFO ] address [0.0.0.0] port [3389] mode 1
Oct 05 14:33:28 xxx_xxx xrdp[7253]: [INFO ] listening to port 3389 on 0.0.0.0
Oct 05 14:33:28 xxx_xxx xrdp[7253]: [INFO ] xrdp_listen_pp done
Oct 05 14:34:05 xxx_xxx xrdp[7253]: [INFO ] Socket 12: AF_INET6 connection received from ::ffff:10.3.230.84 port 57064
Oct 05 14:34:05 xxx_xxx xrdp[7293]: [INFO ] Using default X.509 certificate: /etc/xrdp/cert.pem
Oct 05 14:34:05 xxx_xxx xrdp[7293]: [INFO ] Using default X.509 key file: /etc/xrdp/key.pem
Oct 05 14:34:05 xxx_xxx xrdp[7293]: [INFO ] Security protocol: configured [SSL|RDP], requested [SSL|HYBRID|HYBRID_EX|RDP], selected [SSL]
**Oct 05 14:34:05 xxx_xxx xrdp[7293]: [ERROR] SSL_read: I/O error

Oct 05 14:34:05 xxx_xxx xrdp[7293]: [ERROR] libxrdp_force_read: header read error

Oct 05 14:34:05 xxx_xxx xrdp[7293]: [ERROR] Processing [ITU-T T.125] Connect-Initial failed

Oct 05 14:34:05 xxx_xxx xrdp[7293]: [ERROR] [MCS Connection Sequence] receive connection request failed

Oct 05 14:34:05 xxx_xxx xrdp[7293]: [ERROR] xrdp_sec_incoming: xrdp_mcs_incoming failed

Oct 05 14:34:05 xxx_xxx xrdp[7293]: [ERROR] xrdp_rdp_incoming: xrdp_sec_incoming failed

Oct 05 14:34:05 xxx_xxx xrdp[7293]: [ERROR] xrdp_process_main_loop: libxrdp_process_incoming failed

Oct 05 14:34:05 xxx_xxx xrdp[7293]: [ERROR] xrdp_iso_send: trans_write_copy_s failed

Oct 05 14:34:05 xxx_xxx xrdp[7293]: [ERROR] Sending [ITU T.125] DisconnectProviderUltimatum failed**
Oct 05 14:34:07 xxx_xxx xrdp[7253]: [INFO ] Socket 12: AF_INET6 connection received from ::ffff:10.3.230.84 port 57066
Oct 05 14:34:07 xxx_xxx xrdp[7302]: [INFO ] Using default X.509 certificate: /etc/xrdp/cert.pem
Oct 05 14:34:07 xxx_xxx xrdp[7302]: [INFO ] Using default X.509 key file: /etc/xrdp/key.pem
Oct 05 14:34:07 xxx_xxx xrdp[7302]: [INFO ] Security protocol: configured [SSL|RDP], requested [SSL|HYBRID|HYBRID_EX|RDP], selected [SSL]
Oct 05 14:34:07 xxx_xxx xrdp[7302]: [INFO ] Connected client computer name: xxx_xxx
Oct 05 14:34:07 xxx_xxx xrdp[7302]: [WARN ] Received [MS-RDPBCGR] TS_UD_HEADER type 0xc006 is unknown (ignored)
Oct 05 14:34:07 xxx_xxx xrdp[7302]: [WARN ] Received [MS-RDPBCGR] TS_UD_HEADER type 0xc00a is unknown (ignored)
Oct 05 14:34:07 xxx_xxx xrdp[7302]: [INFO ] xrdp_load_keyboard_layout: Keyboard information sent by the RDP client, keyboard_type:[0x07], keyboard_subtype:[0x02], keylayout:[0xE0010411]
Oct 05 14:34:07 xxx_xxx xrdp[7302]: [INFO ] xrdp_load_keyboard_layout: model [pc105] variant [] layout [jp] options []
Oct 05 14:34:07 xxx_xxx xrdp[7302]: [INFO ] TLS connection established from ::ffff:10.3.230.84 port 57066: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Oct 05 14:34:07 xxx_xxx xrdp[7302]: [INFO ] xrdp_caps_process_pointer: client supports new(color) cursor
Oct 05 14:34:07 xxx_xxx xrdp[7302]: [INFO ] xrdp_process_offscreen_bmpcache: support level 1 cache size 7864320 MB cache entries 100
Oct 05 14:34:07 xxx_xxx xrdp[7302]: [INFO ] xrdp_caps_process_codecs: nscodec, codec id 1, properties len 3
Oct 05 14:34:07 xxx_xxx xrdp[7302]: [WARN ] xrdp_caps_process_codecs: unknown codec id 5
Oct 05 14:34:07 xxx_xxx xrdp[7302]: [INFO ] xrdp_caps_process_codecs: RemoteFX, codec id 3, properties len 49
Oct 05 14:34:07 xxx_xxx xrdp[7302]: [WARN ] Cannot find keymap file /etc/xrdp/km-e0010411.ini
Oct 05 14:34:07 xxx_xxx xrdp[7302]: [INFO ] Loading keymap file /etc/xrdp/km-00000411.ini
Oct 05 14:34:07 xxx_xxx xrdp[7302]: [WARN ] local keymap file for 0xe0010411 found and doesn't match built in keymap, using local keymap file
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp[7302]: [INFO ] connecting to sesman on 127.0.0.1:3350
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7252]: [INFO ] Socket 12: AF_INET6 connection received from ::1 port 51006
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp[7302]: [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: sesman connect ok
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp[7302]: [INFO ] sesman connect ok
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp[7302]: [INFO ] sending login info to session manager. Please wait...
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7252]: [INFO ] Terminal Server Users group is disabled, allowing authentication
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7252]: [INFO ] ++ created session (access granted): username spindle_pcmn, ip ::ffff:10.3.230.84:57066 - socket: 12
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7252]: [INFO ] starting Xorg session...
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7252]: [INFO ] Starting session: session_pid 7317, display :10.0, width 1920, height 1080, bpp 24, client ip ::ffff:10.3.230.84:57066 - socket: 12, user n>
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7317]: [INFO ] [session start] (display 10): calling auth_start_session from pid 7317
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7252]: [ERROR] sesman_data_in: scp_process_msg failed
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp[7302]: [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: login successful for user spindle_pcmn on display 10
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7252]: [ERROR] sesman_main_loop: trans_check_wait_objs failed, removing trans
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp[7302]: [INFO ] login successful for user spindle_pcmn on display 10
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp[7302]: [INFO ] loaded module 'libxup.so' ok, interface size 10296, version 4
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp[7302]: [INFO ] started connecting
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp[7302]: [INFO ] lib_mod_connect: connecting via UNIX socket
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx systemd-logind[1107]: New session c3 of user spindle_pcmn.
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx systemd[1]: Started Session c3 of User spindle_pcmn.
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7317]: pam_unix(xrdp-sesman:session): session opened for user spindle_pcmn(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: [INFO ] Starting X server on display 10: /usr/libexec/Xorg :10 -auth .Xauthority -config xrdp/xorg.conf -noreset -nolisten tcp -logfile .xorgxrdp.%>
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: X.Org X Server 1.20.11
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: Build Operating System:  4.18.0-425.19.2.el8_7.x86_64
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: Current Operating System: Linux xxx_xxx 5.14.0-284.11.1.el9_2.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue May 9 05:49:00 EDT 2023 x86_64
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=(hd0,gpt3)/boot/vmlinuz-5.14.0-284.11.1.el9_2.x86_64 root=UUID=8ce9e372-f51b-4c5d-b7d8-06fea0411431 ro crashkernel=>
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: Build Date: 21 February 2023  12:00:00AM
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: Build ID: xorg-x11-server 1.20.11-17.el9
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: Current version of pixman: 0.40.0
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]:         Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]:         to make sure that you have the latest version.
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]:         (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]:         (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: (++) Log file: ".xorgxrdp.10.log", Time: Thu Oct  5 14:34:19 2023
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: (++) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xrdp/xorg.conf"
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: (==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: xorgxrdpSetup:
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: xrdpdevSetup:
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpmousePlug:
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpkeybPlug:
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpIdentify:
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpDriverFunc: op 10
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpProbe:
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpPreInit:
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpScreenInit: virtualX 800 virtualY 600 rgbBits 8 depth 24
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpScreenInit: pfbMemory bytes 1920000
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpScreenInit: pfbMemory 0x7ff4831c6010
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpSimdInit: assigning yuv functions
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpSimdInit: cpuid ax 1 cx 0 return ax 0x000906a4 bx 0x12400800 cx 0x7ffafbff dx 0xbfebfbff
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpSimdInit: sse2 amd64 yuv functions assigned
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpClientConInit: disconnect idle session after [0] sec
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpClientConInit: kill disconnected [0] timeout [0] sec
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpClientConInit: do_touchpad_scroll_hack [0]
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpXvInit: depth 24
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpScreenInit: out
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpCreateScreenResources:
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpmousePreInit: drv 0x5574c17b6490 info 0x5574c1a8a9a0, flags 0x0
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpmouseControl: what 0
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpmouseDeviceInit:
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpmouseCtrl:
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpRegisterInputCallback: type 1 proc 0x7ff4848a23c0
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpmouseControl: what 1
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpmouseDeviceOn:
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpkeybPreInit: drv 0x5574c17b5580 info 0x5574c1a8d0b0, flags 0x0
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpkeybControl: what 0
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpkeybDeviceInit:
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpkeybChangeKeyboardControl:
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpkeybChangeKeyboardControl: autoRepeat on
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpRegisterInputCallback: type 0 proc 0x7ff48339cd80
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpkeybControl: what 1
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpkeybDeviceOn:
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpDeferredRandR:
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpResizeSession: width 1024 height 768
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]:   calling RRScreenSizeSet
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpRRScreenSetSize: width 1024 height 768 mmWidth 271 mmHeight 203
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpRRGetInfo:
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]:   screen resized to 1024x768
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]:   RRScreenSizeSet ok 1
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpResizeSession: width 1920 height 1080
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]:   calling RRScreenSizeSet
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpRRScreenSetSize: width 1920 height 1080 mmWidth 508 mmHeight 286
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpRRGetInfo:
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]:   screen resized to 1920x1080
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]:   RRScreenSizeSet ok 1
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp[7302]: [INFO ] lib_mod_log_peer: xrdp_pid=7302 connected to X11rdp_pid=7320 X11rdp_uid=1000 X11rdp_gid=1000 client_ip=::ffff:10.3.230.84 client_port=57066
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpClientConGotConnection:
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpClientConGotConnection: g_sck_accept ok new_sck 7
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpClientConGetConnection: idle_disconnect_timeout set to non-positive value, idle timer turned off
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpAddClientConToDev: adding first clientCon 0x5574c1ad7f60
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp[7302]: [INFO ] connected ok
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpClientConProcessMsgVersion: version 0 0 0 1
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpClientConProcessScreenSizeMsg: set width 1920 height 1080 bpp 24
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpClientConAllocateSharedMemory: shmemid 5 shmemptr 0x7ff47a22c000 bytes 8294400
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpClientConProcessMsgClientInput: invalidate x 0 y 0 cx 1920 cy 1080
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpInDeferredRepeatCallback:
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpkeybChangeKeyboardControl:
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpkeybChangeKeyboardControl: autoRepeat off
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7319]: [INFO ] Found X server running at /tmp/.X11-unix/X10
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7317]: [INFO ] Found X server running at /tmp/.X11-unix/X10
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7317]: [INFO ] Session started successfully for user spindle_pcmn on display 10
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7356]: [INFO ] Starting the xrdp channel server for display 10
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7319]: [INFO ] Found X server running at /tmp/.X11-unix/X10
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7317]: [INFO ] Session in progress on display 10, waiting until the window manager (pid 7319) exits to end the session
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7319]: [INFO ] Starting the default window manager on display 10: /usr/libexec/xrdp/startwm-bash.sh
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpClientConProcessMsgClientInfo:
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]:   got client info bytes 7072
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]:   jpeg support 0
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]:   offscreen support 1
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]:   offscreen size 7864320
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]:   offscreen entries 100
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]:   client can not do offscreen to offscreen blits
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]:   client can do new(color) cursor
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]:   client can not do multimon
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpRRSetRdpOutputs: numCrtcs 0 numOutputs 0 monitorCount 0
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpRRSetRdpOutputs: add output 0 left 0 top 0 width 1920 height 1080
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpLoadLayout: keylayout 0xe0010411 variant  display 10
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-chansrv[7356]: [INFO ] Socket 12: AF_UNIX connection received
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpkeybChangeKeyboardControl:
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpkeybChangeKeyboardControl: autoRepeat on
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpkeybChangeKeyboardControl:
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpkeybChangeKeyboardControl: autoRepeat on
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-chansrv[7356]: [INFO ] sound_process_output_format:
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-chansrv[7356]: [INFO ]       wFormatNo       0
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-chansrv[7356]: [INFO ]       wFormatTag      WAVE_FORMAT_PCM
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-chansrv[7356]: [INFO ]       nChannels       2
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-chansrv[7356]: [INFO ]       nSamplesPerSec  44100
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-chansrv[7356]: [INFO ]       nAvgBytesPerSec 176400
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-chansrv[7356]: [INFO ]       nBlockAlign     4
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-chansrv[7356]: [INFO ]       wBitsPerSample  16
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-chansrv[7356]: [INFO ]       cbSize          0
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-chansrv[7356]: [INFO ] sound_process_output_format:
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-chansrv[7356]: [INFO ]       wFormatNo       1
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-chansrv[7356]: [INFO ]       wFormatTag      WAVE_FORMAT_PCM
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-chansrv[7356]: [INFO ]       nChannels       2
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-chansrv[7356]: [INFO ]       nSamplesPerSec  22050
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-chansrv[7356]: [INFO ]       nAvgBytesPerSec 88200
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-chansrv[7356]: [INFO ]       nBlockAlign     4
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-chansrv[7356]: [INFO ]       wBitsPerSample  16
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-chansrv[7356]: [INFO ]       cbSize          0
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpInDeferredRepeatCallback:
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpkeybChangeKeyboardControl:
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpkeybChangeKeyboardControl: autoRepeat off
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpInDeferredRepeatCallback:
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpkeybChangeKeyboardControl:
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpkeybChangeKeyboardControl: autoRepeat off
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-chansrv[7356]: [INFO ] sound_process_training: round trip time 101
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-chansrv[7356]: [INFO ] Detected remote printer 'PRN9' (not supported)
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-chansrv[7356]: [INFO ] Detected remote printer 'PRN8' (not supported)
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-chansrv[7356]: [INFO ] Detected remote printer 'PRN7' (not supported)
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-chansrv[7356]: [INFO ] Detected remote printer 'PRN6' (not supported)
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-chansrv[7356]: [INFO ] Detected remote printer 'PRN5' (not supported)
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-chansrv[7356]: [INFO ] Detected remote printer 'PRN4' (not supported)
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-chansrv[7356]: [INFO ] Detected remote printer 'PRN3' (not supported)
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-chansrv[7356]: [INFO ] Detected remote printer 'PRN2' (not supported)
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-chansrv[7356]: [INFO ] Detected remote printer 'PRN1' (not supported)
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-chansrv[7356]: [INFO ] Detected remote smartcard 'SCARD'
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx gnome-session[7516]: gnome-session-check-accelerated: no X11 display found
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx gnome-session[7521]: gnome-session-check-accelerated: no X11 display found
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx gnome-session[7319]: gnome-session-binary[7319]: WARNING: software acceleration check failed: Child process exited with code 1
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx gnome-session-binary[7319]: WARNING: software acceleration check failed: Child process exited with code 1
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx gnome-session-f[7526]: Cannot open display:
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7317]: [WARN ] Window manager (pid 7319, display 10) exited with non-zero exit code 255 and signal 15. This could indicate a window manager config problem
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7317]: [WARN ] Window manager (pid 7319, display 10) exited quickly (0 secs). This could indicate a window manager config problem
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7317]: [INFO ] Calling auth_stop_session and auth_end from pid 7317
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7317]: pam_unix(xrdp-sesman:session): session closed for user spindle_pcmn
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7317]: [INFO ] Terminating X server (pid 7320) on display 10
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7317]: [INFO ] Terminating the xrdp channel server (pid 7356) on display 10
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpmouseControl: what 2
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpmouseDeviceOff:
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpkeybControl: what 2
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpkeybDeviceOff:
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: xorgxrdpDamageDestroy:
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpkeybControl: what 3
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpkeybUnInit: drv 0x5574c17b5580 info 0x5574c1a8d0b0, flags 0x0
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpUnregisterInputCallback: proc 0x7ff48339cd80
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpmouseControl: what 3
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpmouseUnInit: drv 0x5574c17b6490 info 0x5574c1a8a9a0, flags 0x0
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpUnregisterInputCallback: proc 0x7ff4848a23c0
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpCloseScreen:
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: xorgxrdpDownDown:
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: xorgxrdpDownDown: 1
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpClientConDeinit:
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpClientConDeinit: disconnecting clientCon
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpClientConDisconnect:
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpRemoveClientConFromDev: removing clientCon 0x5574c1ad7f60
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpClientConDeinit: deleting file /run/xrdp/xrdp_display_10
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: rdpClientConDeinit: deleting file /run/xrdp/xrdp_disconnect_display_10
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7356]: Global configuration:
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7356]:     UseUnixSocket (derived):   true
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7356]: Security configuration:
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7356]:     RestrictOutboundClipboard: none
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7356]:     RestrictInboundClipboard:  none
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7356]: Chansrv configuration:
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7356]:     EnableFuseMount            true
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7356]:     FuseMountName:             thinclient_drives
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7356]:     FileMask:                  077
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7356]:     Nautilus 3 Flist Format:   false
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7356]: chansrv::main: using log file [/home/spindle_pcmn/.local/share/xrdp/xrdp-chansrv.10.log]
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx systemd[1]: home-spindle_pcmn-thinclient_drives.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx systemd-logind[1107]: Failed to restore VT, ignoring: Bad file descriptor
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7320]: (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7317]: [INFO ] X server on display 10 (pid 7320) returned exit code 0 and signal number 0
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7317]: [INFO ] xrdp channel server for display 10 (pid 7356) exit code 0 and signal number 0
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7317]: [INFO ] cleanup_sockets:
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7252]: [INFO ] Process 7317 has exited
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx systemd-logind[1107]: Session c3 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.
Oct 05 14:34:19 xxx_xxx xrdp-sesman[7252]: [INFO ] ++ terminated session:  username spindle_pcmn, display :10.0, session_pid 7317, ip ::ffff:10.3.230.84:57066 - socket: 12
Oct 05 14:34:29 xxx_xxx systemd[1]: session-c3.scope: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 05 14:34:29 xxx_xxx systemd-logind[1107]: Removed session c3.

Comment: Xvnc はあくまで Linux 側での VNC サーバかと思いますが、Windows での VNC ビューワは何を使っていますか？もしくは Windows の機能としての「リモートデスクトップ」で繋ごうとしているということでしょうか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。Windows10は「リモートデスクトップ」です。Linux側はxrdp を設置すみで、セッション接続していますが、journalctlのログにあるように、接続後、　「no X11 display found」となり　セッションが削除されます。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini で[Xorg] を有効にしてxrdp.servceを再起動後、windows10のリモートデスクトップでXongにて接続しましたが、同じ現象でした。xorg-x11-server-XWayland.x86_64もインストールされており、[ERROR] SSL_read: I/O error が一因のようです。